# R how to calculate the distance in km between several points that have long and lat

Tags: r

I have three points with long and lat(three islands, see matrix bellow) and, I would like to calculate the distance in km between them. Here is my matrix (list1):

```
list1 <- data.frame(longitude = c(-3.0000,
                                   -1.3333,
                                   -6.5667), 
                     latitude = c(59.0000, 
                                  60.3333,  
                                  62.2500),
                      name= c('Orkney', 
                            'Shetlands', 
                               'Faroe'))
```

I just want to know the distance between the Faroe Islands and the Shetlands, the distance between the shetlands and Orkney and so on and so on... I am a very beginner in R so I am not familiar with the language... can someone help me?

Comment: take a look at `st_distance()` from the `sf`-package, or the distance-functions in the `geosphere`-package

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the distance matrix. It can be done with `geodist` package

```
library(geodist)

distance_matrix <- geodist(list1, measure = 'geodesic' )/1000 #converting it to km

#also, check for other measures in the description

colnames(distance_matrix) <- list1$name
rownames(distance_matrix) <- list1$name
```

Output:

```
            Orkney Shetlands    Faroe
Orkney      0.0000  175.7363 411.2688
Shetlands 175.7363    0.0000 352.4388
Faroe     411.2688  352.4388   0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just don't understand what geodist and geodesic do, like do it calculate the distance + convert it in km? because it seems that the results are given in me... otherwise it makes no sense (those islands are very close to each others)

Comment: Despite the comment in the code, the distances seem to be in metres, as described in the helpfile for geodist. The solution is to divide by 1000.

Comment: My bad. As highlighted by @Miff, I forgot to copy the ```/1000``` part from my code. Updated now.

Comment: @Robagb you can go through the ```geodist``` documentation for details: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geodist/geodist.pdf. Have a look at the top note on Page 3. Alternatively, you can use ```haversine``` , ```vincenty``` or the default ```cheap```.

Comment: @Robagb did it solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

These are two possible solutions:

```r
list1 <- data.frame(longitude = c(-3.0000,
                                  -1.3333,
                                  -6.5667), 
                    latitude = c(59.0000, 
                                 60.3333,  
                                 62.2500),
                    name= c('Orkney', 
                            'Shetlands', 
                            'Faroe'))
require(sf)
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
st_distance(st_as_sf(list1, coords = 1:2, crs=4326))
#> Units: [m]
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,]      0.0 175316.8 410279.5
#> [2,] 175316.8      0.0 351338.2
#> [3,] 410279.5 351338.2      0.0
require(geosphere)
#> Loading required package: geosphere
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(list1[,1:2],1:3), distHaversine, p2=list1[,1:2]))
#>       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> 1      0.0 175512.9 410738.5
#> 2 175512.9      0.0 351731.2
#> 3 410738.5 351731.2      0.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here `coords=1:2` indicates the columns that contain the longitude and latitude this can also done by name for more details see `?st_as_sf`, `crs=4326` stands for the coordinate reference system used (epsg code: https://epsg.io/4326 ). `st_distance` automatically attaches units. If you want different units the units package has example how to convert to different units.

The second example is slightly less fancy and only works for long lat data since it uses `distHaversine` (geosphere contains alternative distance functions). `lapply` is use to calculate each time the distance between one and all other coordinates.

`rownames` and `colnames` can be used to attach the names again. The coordinates stay in the same order.

Comment: Thank you so so much! could you just explain what does it mean the line st_distance(st_as_sf(list1, coords = 1:2, crs=4326)) ? is coords = 1:2 a standard for explaining to R that you are talking with lat and long? what did you use crs=4326 ? is it the most common crs ? how did you put the unit in meters? which function allowed you that? could you explain this function ? do.call(rbind,lapply(split(list1[,1:2],1:3), distHaversine, p2=list1[,1:2])) I am so sorry I am completely beginner

Comment: how do you display the name of the columns and rows ?